# Как выполнить метод после return в web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Код, который должен создать объект, отправить id, а затем обработать в бд.
Проблема в том, что я не понимаю как Сначала вернуть ответ, а уже потом работать с этим объектом в БД.

```
// POST /task
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
        Task task = new Task { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Status = "created", Time = DateTime.Now };
        db.Tasks.Add(task);
        db.SaveChanges();

        //await WaitTwoMinutesAndFinish();
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task t = new System.Threading.Tasks.Task(() => 
        {
            using (db)
            {
                var result = db.Tasks.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == task.Id);
                if (result != null)
                {
                    result.Status = "running";
                    result.Time = DateTime.Now;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                //else
                //return 1;

                Thread.Sleep(3000);

                // status = finished
                result.Status = "finished";
                result.Time = DateTime.Now;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        });
        t.Start();
        //UpdateRecord(task);

        return Accepted(task.Id);
    }
```

Но когда я отсылаю запрос, то вылетает исключение (в строке var result):

```
Cannot access a disposed object. 
A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. 
This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. 
If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
```

Comment: Вы не можете использовать поля класса (в данном случае контекст данных db) после того, как вернули результат из метода. Вам придется создавать этот контекст прямо внутри функции треда, то есть вместо `using (db)` надо написать `using(var mydataconteext = new MyDataContext())` и использовать его

Comment: Хотя я бы, на вашем месте, вообще вместо треда написал асинхронную функцию, чтобы не создавать тред на каждый чих API

Comment: @tym32167 Сможете оформить ответ с примером async метода? А то я не понимаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не интересоваться, зачем это вообще нужно, то можно написать вот такой метод

```
private async Task MyMethod(int taskId)
{
    using (var db = new MyDbContext())
    {
        var result = await db.Tasks.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == task.Id);
        if (result != null)
        {
            result.Status = "running";
            result.Time = DateTime.Now;
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        //else
        //return 1;

        await Task.Delay(3000);

        // status = finished
        result.Status = "finished";
        result.Time = DateTime.Now;
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }   
}
```

и вызвать его из вашего кода так

```
MyMethod(task.Id)
```

Это не создаст нового треда и должно отработать. Но зачем вообще это делать мне не ясно.

Чтобы иметь возможность создать контекст данных, можно прокинуть сервис провайдер, который является контейнером по умолчанию. Пример как это делать:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    public ValuesController(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        Foo();
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }     

    private async void Foo()  
    {
        using(var db = (MyDataContext)_serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(MyDataContext)))
        {
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: но в таком случае он даже не входит в MyMethod. Он только создает, а при вызове не меняет статус на running

Comment: @kot_mapku3 Поставьте все, что внутри метода, в try-catch и логгируйте ошибку, мне кажется, у вас где то ошибка просто вылезает, потому и не отрабатывает.

Comment: Ошибка вылезает после вызова функции. Например, она все отработала, но потом та что выше уже писал вылазит после завершения метода. И тут еще такой вопрос, как мне пересоздать DbContext. Он при var db = MyContext() создает пустой экземпляр получается и не коннектится к бд.

Comment: https://ibb.co/hRhTMT

Comment: @kot_mapku3 вам нельзя передавать в такую функцию контекст, так как функция может ещё работать, когда класс уже не работает. Если вам надо создать контекст со строкой подключения, передавайте в него строку подключения.

Comment: Не работает оно так. В asp.net core у entity встроенного нет таких свойств и конструктора

Comment: @kot_mapku3 обновил ответ.

Comment: Я еще тут обнаружил, что db context существует только во время запроса, а затем очищается и то, что после SaveChanges он тоже вызывает Dispose. Короче, спасибо большое!